# Self invoking function via setTimeout within object

Tags: javascript, function, object, self-invoking-function

I would like invoke a method of an js object within the very same object method via `setTimeout`:

```
var ads = {

  init: function() {
    ads.display_ads();
  },

  display_ads: function() {
     console.log('Displaying Ads');
     setTimeout('ads.display_ads()', 5000);
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

```
ads is not defined

setTimeout('ads.display_ads()', 2000);
```

What am I missing here? How would i alter the string within the setTimeout function?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I use firefox on mac.

Comment: If you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it is evaluated in global scope. Apparently, `ads` is not defined in global scope. The solution is not to pass a string. This has **nothing** to do with the fact that you call `setTimeout` in a function associated to an object property.

Comment: I see no error on chrome. Which browser are you on?

Comment: Using strings in setTimout is just as bad as using eval()

Comment: Inside `init`, you really should call `this.display_ads()` instead of `ads....`. Otherwise you might run into problems if you rename the variable or assign the object to another variable etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to `ads.display_ads`, note that this is not a `String`. i.e.

```
var ads = {
    init: function() {
        ads.display_ads();
    },
    display_ads: function() {
        console.log('Displaying Ads');
        setTimeout(ads.display_ads, 5000);
    }
}
```

As @FelixKling points out in his comment below, be careful about what `this` refers to in `ads.display_ads`. If `ads.display_ads` is called via `ads.init()` or  `ads.display_ads()` `this` will be the `ads` `Object`. However, if called via `setTimeout` `this` will be `window`.

If the context is important though, you can pass an anonymous function to `setTimeout`, which in turn calls `ads.display_ads()`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    ads.display_ads();
}, 5000);
```

or

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.display_ads();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Inside `display_ads`, `this` will then refer to `window`. This might not be a problem, but is important to point out.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. This was an eye-opener. =)

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Thanks to @FelixKling too for flagging up the binding issue.

Answer (score 0):

try `this.display_ads`,

I'd recommend you to use this for referencing `ads`

so the code will be like:

```
var ads = {

  init: function() {
    this.display_ads();
  },

  display_ads: function() {
     console.log('Displaying Ads');
     setTimeout(this.display_ads, 5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work the first time. When `this.display_ads` is executed a second time (through `setTimeout`), `this.display_ads` will be `undefined`, as `this` refers to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

So, like jakeclarkson said, ads.display_ads:

```
setTimeout(hitch(ads, ads.display_ads), 5000);
```

The difference is that you should use a "hitch" function:

```
function hitch(scope, callback) {
    return function () {
         return callback.apply(scope, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
}
```

This function will ensure that the scope of the callback is your ads object.  See MDN for a description of the apply function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500005/1703727) of [jabclab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071383/jabclab) helped me greatly. I was trying to get a game loop to work, but it seems `this` was referencing `window` instead of the object I created. Here is a minimal version of the now running code (it just counts up each second and writes it into a div "content"):

```
function Game(model, renderer){
    this.model = model;
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.run = function(){
        this.model.update();
        this.renderer.draw(this.model);
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){self.run();}, 1000);
    };
}
function Model(){
    this.data = 0;
    this.update = function(){
        this.data++;
    };
}
function Renderer(){
    this.draw = function(model, interpolation){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = model.data;
    };
}
var game = new Game(new Model(), new Renderer());
game.run();
```

Instead of `setTimeout(this.run, 1000)` I used `self` instead of `this` to clarify which object is meant (as suggested by [jabclab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071383/jabclab)). Thought I'd add this because I'm using an object constructor and has a slightly different syntax. Especially using `ads.method` didn't work (because Game is not an object yet I guess), so I had to use the last solution.